# Opening and closing activity with animation not working on back pressed but working for opening

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am opening an activity with animation (sliding left to right). I also want it close sliding right to left on back pressed. But Animation only working on activity open. Not working on close. It just closes normally without slide animation.

Here is my code:

slide_in.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <translate 
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
                  android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
                  android:toXDelta="0%p">
            </translate>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <translate
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                 android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
                 android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
                 android:toXDelta="-100%p">
          </translate>
```

Inside onCreate of second activity

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

But it is only working for opening activity. Animation not working for closing activity. What is missing or wrong with my code? How can I get it work on closing activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `overridePendingTransition` just after your `startActivity` method.

Comment: I tried it. But still close animation not working. :(

Comment: Try to call `overridePendingTransition` just after your `startActivity` method